# downloadHandler() function can not download ROC curves generated by pROC::plot.roc in ShinyApps

Tags: r, shiny, proc

I tried to generate a ROC plot using pROC::plot.roc(), while I can not download it by downloadHandler(). The plot can be displayed by renderPlot().

The code that i used is as follow:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(pROC)
    density_for_roc = structure(list(outcome = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
                                                 "R", "R", "R", "R", "N", "N", "R", "R", "R", "N", "N", "R", "N"
    ), AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1 = c(0.017727954, 0.058801247, 0.015206073, 
                                0.03841438, 0.021110919, 0.121350173, 0.024798968, 0.021174954, 
                                0.041613777, 0.041826562, 0.031736561, 0.039073795, 0.037008846, 
                                0.039844069, 0.015128107, 0.072872415, 0.150001678, 0.046815947, 
                                0.064343284, 0.030063415), AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2 = c(0.01199244, 
                                                                                    0.002389347, 0.002362331, 0.000464258, 0.001211282, 0.003326839, 
                                                                                    0.037676998, 0.009736181, 0.0013208, 0.029663772, 0.031878623, 
                                                                                    0.000579845, 0.018544344, 0, 0.001678287, 0.012931236, 0.015694521, 
                                                                                    0.000777618, 0.00715926, 0.026905713), A3 = c(0.0250277, 0.017453889, 
                                                                                                                                  0.019196807, 0.043711684, 0.059439349, 0.05482742, 0.032754805, 
                                                                                                                                  0.03542383, 0.03845758, 0.035652267, 0.03196386, 0.036135916, 
                                                                                                                                  0.035278964, 0.018358189, 0.006477872, 0.038186826, 0.068229557, 
                                                                                                                                  0.030991839, 0.042955559, 0.021581983), AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4 = c(0.001173173, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.006964072, 0.000550446, 0.002428427, 0.012761723, 0.017078083, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.03519881, 0.094964956, 0.005145974, 0.028727624, 0.023582225, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.000108238, 0.002304736, 0.009020443, 0.000611712, 0.024088511, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.002478553, 0.000347002, 0.003692197, 0.01834599), AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA5 = c(0.005214104, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.001952271, 0.0000229, 0.0000595, 0.000605641, 0.000163538, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.000632365, 0.0000165, 0.001080655, 0.000628863, 0.000142062, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0000232, 0.007542289, 0, 0.000917568, 0.005601979, 0.00614717, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.000234122, 0, 0.000469741)), row.names = c("146552", "150717", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "157628", "166566", "166938", "167456", "170593", "171695", "171761", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "173707", "179165", "180545", "184356", "185176", "185872", "186694", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "187317", "187748", "188120", "188567"), class = "data.frame")
      
      
    cell_list = colnames(density_for_roc)[2: ncol(density_for_roc)]
    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput("cell_marker_density_roc", "Cell type", choices = cell_list, 
                  selected = colnames(density)[1]),
      plotOutput("density_roc_plot_1_output", width = "520px", height = "520px"),
      downloadButton('density_roc_plot_1_downloadPlot','Download Plot')
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      density_roc_plot_1 <- eventReactive(
        c(input$cell_marker_density_roc
        ), {
          cell_marker = input$cell_marker_density_roc
          density_roc_data = density_for_roc[, c("outcome", cell_marker)]
          cols = "red"
          p = plot.roc(density_roc_data[, 1],
                       density_roc_data[, 2],
                       xlim = c(1, 0),ylim = c(0, 1), 
                       smooth = TRUE, 
                       col = cols,
                       lwd = 4, 
                       identity.col = "black",
                       ci = FALSE,
                       legacy.axes = T)
          auc.val.legend = signif(p$auc, digits = 3)

          legend.name = paste0("AUC of ", cell_marker, " = ", auc.val.legend)
          
          legend(x = max(nchar(legend.name)) * 0.029, y = length(legend.name) * 0.0615,
                 legend = legend.name,
                 col = cols,
                 lwd = 4, bty = "n")
        }
      )
      
      
      
      output$density_roc_plot_1_output <- renderPlot({
        if(length(input$cell_marker_density_roc) > 5) {
          validate("Please select no more than 5 items"
          )
        }
        density_roc_plot_1()
      }, res = 96)
      
      
      output$density_roc_plot_1_downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
          paste("plot.pdf")
        },
        content = function(file) {
          pdf(file, width = 6,height = 6)
          print(density_roc_plot_1(), newpage = FALSE)
          dev.off()
        }
      )
      
    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I think the problem is that the output using the print() function is incorrect. I tried to remove the print() function but it still didn't work.